# C# - Write DateTime field (with NaNo Second) to text file (using Streamwriter)

Tags: c#

See below, where dataset is returning the results from tables.

Dataset returns column which are DATETIME, but with below code - NANO seconds are removed when written to file.

For e.g
Source Data: 2014-01-01 01:23:55.596

Whats getting written in file is
Output Data: 2014-01-01 01:23:55

So I want to tweak the below code, so that NANO seconds also get printed to file.

```
try
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection(str_ConnectionString1))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString1, connection1);
        command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        connection1.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();

        // This size is just for example purpose. Should be fine tuned
        StreamWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter(@str_FeedFilePath1 + @str_FileName1);
        var result = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder buffer1 = new StringBuilder(1048576);
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < reader1.FieldCount; j++)
            {
                buffer1.Append(reader1[j] + "|");
            }
            buffer1.AppendLine();
            if (buffer1.Length > 1048576 - 1024)
            {
                writer1.Write(buffer1.ToString());
                buffer1.Length = 0;
            }
        }
        writer1.Write(buffer1.ToString());
        writer1.WriteLine(result);
        reader1.Close();
        writer1.Close();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title says VB.NET, your tags say C# and VB.NET, your code is C#.  Make your mind up.

Comment: First identify your datetime column index at `buffer1.Append(reader1[j] + "|");` then you can use `.ToString(...)` to format it as you would like.

Comment: I think you mean milliseconds... A Nanosecond is equal to one-billionth of a second!

Comment: Do you mean milliseconds or nanoseconds or NaN - not a number?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the object returned from the reader. It will look something like this:

```
if (reader1[j] is DateTime)
   buffer1.Append(((DateTime)reader1[j]).ToString("o"));
else
   buffer1.Append(reader1[j]);
buffer1.Append("|");
...
```

PS: DateTime is only accurate to 100ns, and unless you are using MS's DateTime2 field, you may be even less accurate than that in the DB. Did you mean milliseconds?

Comment: The Sql query will return multiple columns,  which will have text and date field. So how to handle this or you think above will work if Sql query returns multiple columns